# Strange Random Behavior in a Local Variable of a Function

Tags: c, function, printf, undefined-behavior, garbage

I'm trying to write a program that finds the distance of an arbitrary amount of tugboats from a main ship and orders them from closest to furthest. This also involves removing tugboats that are deemd to be at an invalid location. However, in my sorting function I've encountered strange and seemingly inexplicable behavior in one of the local variables named validTugboatCount. This function is shown below:

```
void sortTugboats(tugboat * unsorted, long long int tugboatCount){
        long long int validTugboatCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tugboatCount; i++){
            if(!unsorted[i].isInvalid)
                validTugboatCount++;
        } //ValidTugboatCount holds correct data, e.g 4


        tugboat validUnsorteds[validTugboatCount]; //validTugboatCount is still at 4

        for(int i = 0; i < tugboatCount; i++){
            if(!unsorted[i].isInvalid)
                validUnsorteds[i] = unsorted[i];
        }

        mergeSort(validUnsorteds, 0, validTugboatCount-1); //validTugboatCount's value inexplicably changes here, e.g becoming 140733193388031 in one instance

        unsorted = validUnsorteds;
    }
```

Weirdly enough, after introducing a printf() call to display the value of validTugboatCount right after the first for loop establishing its value, the problem seemingly corrects itself, as shown below:

```
void sortTugboats(tugboat * unsorted, long long int tugboatCount){
        long long int validTugboatCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tugboatCount; i++){
            if(!unsorted[i].isInvalid)
                validTugboatCount++;
        } //validTugboatCount holds correct data, e.g 4

        printf("%lld\n", validTugboatCount); //printf prints "4"

        tugboat validUnsorteds[validTugboatCount]; //array becomes size 4

        for(int i = 0; i < tugboatCount; i++){
            if(!unsorted[i].isInvalid)
                validUnsorteds[i] = unsorted[i];
        }

        mergeSort(validUnsorteds, 0, validTugboatCount-1); //validTugboatCount is at 4??

        unsorted = validUnsorteds;
    }
```

My initial guess was that the issue has something to do with the conversion of long long ints to ints, but even after converting every function's arguments to long long ints the problem still persists. This also doesn't explain why the issue corrects itself after inserting a printf(). Help would be greatly appreciated.

[validTugboatCount is at 4 right before the call to mergeSort()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBMrA.png)

[value changes?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVNmv.png)

[With the addition of the printf() statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5C2i.png)

[validTugboatCount remains 4??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv8n7.png)

Tried: creating a variable that would store the number of valid tugboats by looping through a list of all tugboats and seeing whether the isInvalid flag is set to 0

Expected: validTugboatCount would hold the correct amount of valid tugboats

Actual: validTugboatCount holds correct data at first and then suddenly switches to holding random garbage data, always an extremely large number

Comment: `unsorted = validUnsorteds;` But `validnsorted` stops _existing_ after the function exits.

Comment: @KamilCuk I realized that issue and will be replacing that line with memcpy or an equivalent

Comment: After you copy the valid and sorted array, you also need to tell the calling code how many valid tugboats there are.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was planning on converting the tugboat array pointers to a 'tugboatList' struct that would hold it's length as a variable in the struct

Answer (score 0):

As for the statement "tugboat validUnsorteds[validTugboatCount];" Will there be enough memory for a local variable array of that size?  The stack's size is limited. I'd suggest using the heap instead.

Strange behaviour that is fixed by a printf was  on my side often a result of another function  not always returning a value when it should do so.

E.g.
int32_t a(void) {

```
// do stuff but no return statement
```

}

might sometimes lead to strange behaviour in other parts of the program.

Do all your other functions that return values do so in all  execution parts?

Comment: The initial tugboatCount variable that is fed into the function has a hardcoded limit on its size earlier in the program. My program also doesn't have any functions with return values, and even if it did how would that affect the data in validTugboatCount?

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
        tugboat validUnsorteds[validTugboatCount]; //validTugboatCount is still at 4

        for(int i = 0; i < tugboatCount; i++){
            if(!unsorted[i].isInvalid)
                validUnsorteds[i] = unsorted[i];
        }
```

you've created a temp array with enough space for `validTugboatCount` entries, but then you're writing at indexes up to `tugboatCount - 1`.  So if validTugboatCount < tugboatCount (which seems likely), you'll write out of bounds and Undefined Behavior will ensue.

You probably want something like:

```
        tugboat validUnsorteds[validTugboatCount]; //validTugboatCount is still at 4

        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < tugboatCount; i++){
            if(!unsorted[i].isInvalid)
                validUnsorteds[j++] = unsorted[i];
        }
```